# Hacer diagonal en CSS

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando recrear una imagen en CSS pero no me sale la "diagonal" como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: Encabezado con diagonales]

Hasta ahora solo pude sobreponer los dos colores creando 3 div's, el contenedor, el azul y el dorado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les anexo mi html y css:

```css
body{
    background: white;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}

.encabezado{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.azul {
    background: rgba(0,125,204,.95);

    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;

}

.dorado{
    background: rgb(212,176,18);
    width: 35%;
    right: 0px;
    height: 65px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="encabezado">
    <div class="azul"></div>
    <div class="dorado"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una opción sería usando las pseudo-elementos `::before` y `::after` para generar ese efecto. Así lo que harías sería añadir un `::before`/`::after` cuadrado y transformado para que tenga esa forma (por ejemplo con `rotate` o `skew`).

Algo como esto (he quitado el color de fondo de .azul y lo he puesto en su `::after` para que no haya problemas con las opacidades):

```css
body {
  background: white;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.encabezado {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.azul {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.azul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  width: 120%;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 125, 204, .95);
  transform: skew(40deg);
}

.dorado {
  background: rgb(212, 176, 18);
  width: 35%;
  right: 0px;
  height: 65px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dorado::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -32px;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  background: rgb(212, 176, 18);
  transform: skew(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="encabezado">
  <div class="azul"></div>
  <div class="dorado"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Optare por esta como la respuesta a mi solución, gracias por las respuestas.

Answer (score 3):

Para hacer diagonales puedes usar `polygon` de css que sirve para dar formas a los elementos de html además si creas una clase y agregas como lo hice yo y además agregas clases de bootstrap por ejemplo, no interfiere mucho , de hecho casi nada.Y no se limita solo a diagonales puedes hacer muchas formas geométricas por porcentaje.

```css
body{
    background: white;
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}

.encabezado{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.azul {
    background: rgba(0,125,204,.95);
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 96% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 96% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);

}

.dorado{
    background: rgb(212,176,18);
    width: 35%;
    right: 0px;
    height: 65px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 10% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 10% 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="encabezado">
    <div class="azul"></div>
    <div class="dorado"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Te dejo el [LINK DE FORMAS](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/), en esta página solo busca la forma , editas de la forma que quieres y además te genera abajo el código css automáticamente.

> PD: Funciona en divs.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si lo haría pero no tenía tiempo , por eso le deje todo eso para que lo adaptara , cuando llegue a la casa editare esta respues, vale?

Comment: @Member ahí cambie mi codigo para que se adapte al tuyo

Answer (score 2):

Tiene una manera súper fácil de hacer esto. Usted puede transformar su imagen en HTML / CSS. Después, convertir esto en SVG! O, si tiene las dimensiones y tamaños y el patrón de cada elemento crear clases con CSS referentes a esto a su HTML. O usted puede usar el propio 'Inspeccionar Elemento' para saber el tamaño de cada cosa y el color. Y así, volver a crear el elemento con estos datos, información. O, usted puede simplemente utilizar paper.js para hacer ese proceso para usted.

Información

- https://javier.xyz/img2css/ ( PNG / JPG para CSS/HTML )
- http://paperjs.org/              ( Biblioteca Javascript para crear cosas legales )
- https://editor.method.ac/        ( Editor SVG )
- http://vectorpaint.yaks.co.nz/   ( Editor SVG )