# Como sesgar un div con css?

Tags: html, css

quiero sesgar un div para que quede como en la imagen. Y no tengo absoluta idea para hacerlo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #76cad4;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px grey;  
}
.fondo-img{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="fondo-img"><img src="img/logo-stucom.png"></div>
    </header>
```

[Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvZXP.png)

Comment: otra pregunta similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163682/hacer-diagonal-en-css

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido al sitio, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask]. Te recomiendo revisar también: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%C3%A9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%C3%B3n/3196#3196

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de sesgar te doy una solución alternativa: utilizar un gradiente lineal de esta manera:

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: 
  linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f5f5 0%, #f5f5f5 50%, #76cad4 50%, #76cad4 100%);
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px grey;  
}
.fondo-img{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;    
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="fondo-img"><img src="img/logo-stucom.png"></div>
</header>
```